# StatefulBuilder vs ValueListenableBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

I came across [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)  class in Flutter but I cannot understand this:

What is the difference between [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) and [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) and when to use one of them?

I have this question because `ValueListenableBuilder` can rebuild the part of the UI when the `valueListenable` changes but we can achieve the same result with `StatefulBuilder` by calling the `setState` method.

Comment: imagine you got `ValueListenable` from somewhere - now in order to use it with `StatefulBuilder` you need to `addListener` and call `setState` from the listener, with `ValueListenableBuilder` you just pass `ValueListenable` in the ctor

Comment: I understand that. My question is why do we even need `StatefulBuilder` when we can use `ValueListenableBuilder` instead to re-build only part of the UI?

Comment: Because you need to have a `ValueNotifier` as the `valueListenable` property for `ValueListenableBuilder` while on the `StatefulBuilder` you can go good old `setState` for just the state inside this builder. I actually like to use it for some small dialogs or bottom sheets where I need to update just the dialog UI (very small part)

Comment: *"My question is why do we even need StatefulBuilder"* - well, use `StatefulBuilder` when you dont have / dont want to create `ValueListenable` - basically both use `StatefulWidget` under the hood - only the interface differs

Comment: @kounex Thanks for the answer, Is there any difference in the performance between them?

Comment: basically both use `StatefulWidget` under the hood - only the interface differs (public API)

Comment: sure, your welcome - btw there is also `AnimatedBuilder` ;-)